# How to put an array into a file?

Tags: php, arrays

I do this to get file content into array:

```
$array = file('sample.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

How to reverse this? If I have the array already how to write it to a file, each value in a seperate line.

Comment: I want to say there is a way to `var_dump` or something to a variable (using a buffer) and then pull that back into a variable with another function...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would not make sense to put each value on a different row. You're probably looking for [serialize](http://php.net/serialize).

If you really want each element on it's own line, you could use [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
$str = implode("\n", $array);
file_put_contents($file, $str);
```

Comment: Serialized data would not be helpful if the file output is going to be used elsewhere. Why do you feel that it would not make sense to write data to a file in the way the OP described?

Comment: @George Why do we assume that it's going to be used elsewhere? If that's a problem, the OP should mention it.

Comment: I don't think we need to make any assumption at all. The OP asked for it, so he must have a need.

Comment: First, I convert the file to array (then find in_array() search if something exists then do some operation with it) later I need to put the left array back to another file.. I have a use for this :)

Comment: @Ahmad Then you should be perfectly fine with using implode.

Comment: It would be even better to use "\r\n" instead of "\n".

Comment: @Hexodus Yeah, or even PHP_EOL.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function instead of file(). Using that function you will get a string, and that can be easily written to file by [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

To make a string from the array you can use [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
$string = implode("\n", $array);
file_put_contents("file.txt", $string);
```

To store an array you have to [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) it to make a string.

Answer (score 1):

[serialize](http://php.net/serialize) the array before writing and [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) to get the array back.

Answer (score 0):

You can [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) the array or try this:

```
$result = implode(PHP_EOL, $array);
file_put_contents('sample.txt', $result);
```